# Mappings with @="^E" result in @="" and do nothing

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

It seems that mappings with `@="^E"` or `@="<c-e>"` result in `@=""` and do nothing.

For example if I use `nnoremap ^N @="^E"^M` then press <kbd>ctrl-n</kbd> I will get a `@=""` message and nothing happens. However, when I use `nnoremap ^N @="^Y"^M` then press <kbd>ctrl-n</kbd> I receive a `@="^Y"` message and the screen scrolls down.

I should also mention that if I enter `@="^E"^M` manually, -- and not as a mapping -- it works just fine.

To clarify I want to know how to pass `<c-e>` into the expression register because I want to be able to use it in repeatable mappings. Such as `nnoremap <c-p> @="<c-e>j"` to scroll the window and move cursor down n lines.

Comment: What do you expect to happen exactly?

Comment: I expect it to scroll one line up, and show a `@="^E"` message. I'm perplexed as to why it wont work for `<c-e>` but will for seemingly any other `<c-...>` character.

Comment: `nnoremap <C-n> <C-e>`

Comment: I ran into this problem because I wanted to have a mapping like `nnoremap <c-n> @="<c-e>j"`; that scrolls the window and moves my cursor down at the same time. The @= makes it so the operation is repeatable. ie I can press `10` `ctrl-n` to scroll the window, and move cursor 10 lines down. `nnoremap <c-n> <c-e>j` scrolls the window down 10 but the cursor only goes down 1. The mapping `nnoremap <c-p> @="<c-y>k"` which does the exact opposite, works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `:help c_ctrl-e`:

```
CTRL-E or <End>                 *c_CTRL-E* *c_<End>* *c_End*
                cursor to end of command-line
```

In command-line mode, `<C-e>` moves the cursor to the end of the line, and when you are inside the expression register `=`, you are on the command-line.

So, when you hit `<C-N>` in normal mode, here's what Vim does:

- type `@="`
- move the cursor to the end of the command-line (it's already at the end anyway) because of `^E` ; it doesn't insert the character `^E` because the latter was interpreted as a motion
- type `"^M`

In the end, it's as if you had typed: `@=""`, which is an empty string.  So, Vim doesn't execute anything.

It would work if there was something in the string, for example if you type `@="dd"` in normal mode, it will delete the current line. But here, there's nothing left in the string, because `^E` was interpreted as a motion.

For this reason, you can't use `^E` in your mapping.

---

Your mapping works for `^Y` because of this (`:help c_ctrl-y`):

```
CTRL-Y      When there is a modeless selection, copy the selection into
            the clipboard. |modeless-selection|
            If there is no selection CTRL-Y is inserted as a character.
```

Like `^E`, `^Y` is associated with an action on the command-line. But not if there is no selection.
In this case, contrary to `^E`, it simply inserts a literal control character.

---

Depending on the context, there are various ways to write a control character like `^E`:

- `^E` (<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-E</kbd>) to insert it on the command-line or in a buffer
- `<C-E>` in a mapping
- `"\<C-E>"` in a string
- `"\<lt>C-E>"` in a string read by a mapping command such as `:nnoremap`

So, if for some reason you really wanted to use the expression register (maybe because you wanted to create a [mapping](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/creating-mappings-that-accept-a-count/) accepting a count), you could use `"\<lt>C-E>"`, like this:

```
nnoremap ^N @="\<lt>C-E>"^M
```

In this mapping, 2 translations occur at different times.

First, when your `:nnoremap` command is executed and add an entry in the mappings table, the keycode `<lt>` is translated as the character `<`, and the resulting string is `"\<C-E>"`.
Then, when you hit `<C-N>` in normal mode, the string `"\<C-E>"` is translated into the control character `^E`.

The keycode `<lt>` is necessary to protect `<C-E>` from being automatically translated into a literal control character when `:nnoremap` is executed.
If you don't protect `<C-E>` with `<lt>`, the same problem as before will repeat; `^E` will be intepreted as a motion on the command-line instead of a character to insert.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly the information I needed.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're not using the good way to do what you want:

The expression register (`"=`) is a way to evaluate an expression but what you are trying to use (<kbd>Ctrl-E</kbd>) is simply a normal mode command.

So a in a normal mode mapping you can simply use it directly with `:nnoremap <C-n> <C-e>` (or `:nnoremap <C-n> <C-y>` or whatever). You don't need to consider that as an expression to be executed.

Generally speaking I don't think it is a good idea to use the expression register since it adds complexity to your mapping whereas you often have an other solution to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm sorry, I oversimplified my original question to point out the problem. I need the expression register because I'm trying to create a repeatable command that uses `ctrl-e` `j` ie @="<c-e>j" to move the screen and cursor down n lines. You need an expression register for that to be executed properly. I was also curious as to why <c-e> wouldn't work in the mapping.