# Why doesn't this macro work? (expression register)

Tags: key-bindings, macro

According to [this](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/creating-mappings-that-accept-a-count/):

> `nnoremap Q @='n.'<CR>`: The @ key tells Vim to execute a macro. Rather than using a named register we use the expression register, which lets us specify the contents in place. The characters inside of the quotes are interpreted as keystrokes, and the carriage return enters the string into the expression register.

But I tried this:

`nnoremap K @='k<C-Y>'<CR>` <s>and it doesn't work.</s>   Edit: nevermind, this one works, but this one doesn't:
`noremap J @="j<C-E>"<CR>`

Edit: I was also trying to make `noremap J @="j<C-E>"<CR>` work. But one of the comments below links to a question and explains why this one doesn't work: [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7437/17449)

Comment: it works for me (although I'm not sure why you'd use this instead of `nnoremap K k<c-y>`

Comment: It works? It is supposed to move the cursor one line upwards using k and the window one line downwards (using CTRL-Y). Is that what it is doing? Oh and the reason for this format is because I want to be able to do the command with a Count before, such as 12K.

Comment: `'<C-Y>'` **is not** ctrl-y.

Comment: @Matt I figured that could be the problem. How do I use ctrl-y in vim expression strings then (if that's what they are called)?

Comment: @Matt doesn't matter, since nnoremap replaces `<c-y>` for you.  It works fine on my vim.

Comment: Doesn't work on my vim for some reason. It's not executing the right bindings

Comment: I meant `nnoremap K @="k\<lt>C-Y>"<CR>` but, as it turns out, that one should also work. @Zaid You probably have some other mapping for `<C-Y>` or such.

Comment: I'm not sure why your mapping using an expression doesn't work but it looks way over complicated to me. Why not simply using a regular mapping which accepts a count like this? `nnoremap K :<C-U>execute 'normal! '. v:count1 . 'k' . v:count1 . '<C-Y>'<CR>` Maybe you'll need to read [`:h :execute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute) and [`:h v:count1`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3Acount1) but that should make it much easier to read, to understand and to debug if needed

Comment: @Matt your macro works (```nnoremap K @="k\<lt>C-Y>"<CR>```). Thanks! The other one (the one you said "as it turns out it also should work"), does NOT work. I don't have conflicting bindings anywhere as I removed all other bindings from .vimrc. Could you explain what the ```\<lt>C-Y>``` does?

Comment: Read `:help <>`

Comment: @ZaidGharaybeh See this answer: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7437/17449

Comment: Thanks. This seems to explain why ```nnoremap K @="k\<C-Y>"<CR>``` works but ```nnoremap J @="j\<C-E>"<CR>``` doesn't. However, ```nnoremap K @='k<C-Y>'<CR>``` still doesn't work.

Comment: *However, nnoremap K @='k<C-Y>'<CR> still doesn't work.* It works for me.  Try to reproduce without config `vim -Nu NONE +"nnoremap K @='k<C-Y>'<CR>"`.

Comment: Actually, I tried ```nnoremap K @='k<C-Y>'<CR>``` again and it works. I don't know why I said it doesn't I probably missed something. This one doesn't, though: ```nnoremap K @='k\<C-Y>'<CR>```, but I think husB's answer below explains why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of quotes in Vim, `'...'`, and `"..."`. These are treated differently.

The first `'...'` is a *literal string*. It is taken as-is. No characters have a special meaning, including `<`,`>`,`\`.

The second `"..."` is a *quoted string*. It accepts special characters, which are prepended with a backslash (`\`).

In your case, `<C-Y>` is denotes the special character CTRL-Y. Thus, to include this character in your expression, you should use the double quotes with a backslash (`"\<C-Y>"`).

Putting it together, the mapping would be changed to

```
nnoremap K @="k\<C-Y>"<CR>
```

For more, see

- `:h expr-'`
- `:h expr-"`

---

**Edit:** For a similar mapping to `J`, `nnoremap J @="j\<C-E>"<CR>` would not work, as `<C-E>` gets 'used up' in the (expression register) command line. This is further explained [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7437/17449), and in the comments. A better way would be to escape it with `\<lt>`, as proposed in the comments.

Thus,

```
nnoremap K @="k\<lt>C-Y>"<CR>
nnoremap J @="j\<lt>C-E>"<CR>
```

Comment: For some reason, ```nnoremap J @="j\<C-E>"<CR>``` doesn't work. ```nnoremap K @="k\<C-Y>"<CR>``` does. :S
This is the error I get:
="j\"
E114: Missing quote: "j\"
Press ENTER or type command to continue

Comment: I think the latest comment added by user938271 to the question explains it: vi.stackexchange.com/a/7437/17449

Comment: Good find. TIL.

Comment: The `:map` commands are special in that they expand the `<...>` key sequences. So to get what you're proposing here, you actually need `nnoremap K @="k\<lt>C-Y>"<CR>`, more specifically use a `<lt>` to prevent `:map` from expanding the `<C-Y>` prematurely. But having said that, since `:map` expands the `<C-Y>`, it actually *should* work with the single quotes, having the `:map` expand the special characters...

Comment: Agreed, thank you :) Allow me to edit my answer